# Bootstrap dropdown menu with href link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootsrtap to build a toggleable dropdown menu.

So I use an "a" tag that when I click on it it open a dropdown menu, here is my code :

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
        <a id="my-dropdown" href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
    
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
    
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to open a href link in the same time when the dropdown :

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
        <a id="my-dropdown" href="#section=mysection" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
    
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
    
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work,

Any idea ?

Comment: You can't use `=` sign in your href attribute.

Comment: I m pretty sure that I can use the "=" sign in a href ... i'm using it all over my app.. and it works correctly ... here is an example :

 <a href="/site/cepps/home.html#section=home-patient">Accueil Patient</a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/3258604 Look at this answer (reserved characters).

Comment: can you explain more about it,  and  what is this `#section=mysection`

Comment: can you explain more about it,  and  what is this `#section=mysection`,
cant open your drop down menu , your are using href tag to  `#section=mysection` why are you used it

Answer (score 2):

Use - Bootstrap **CDN** correctly
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="dropdown">
        <a id="my-dropdown" href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
    
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the "#" before the "section".
I'm not totally sure that will fix your issue.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
        <a id="my-dropdown" href="section=mysection" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
    
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: No, it does not resolve the issue, it do not open the href automatically !

Comment: Like makshh said, you can't use the = sign in href attribute. Read this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: I m pretty sure that I can use the "=" sign in a href ... i'm using it all over my app.. here is an example :

 <a href="/site/cepps/home.html#section=home-patient">Accueil Patient</a>